# Validate UDP checksum in a Linux netfilter hook

Tags: linux-kernel, udp, hook, checksum, netfilter

I'm processing/modifying UDP datagrams for local delivery within a netfilter hook in Linux kernel version > 4.x at the NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING chain. However, before I start modifying such datagrams I want to validate their consistency by checking their checksum. How is the most efficient way to do so?

Since I assume, that the IP layer is already passed and thereby IP header consistency is already given, is it enough if I validate with:

```c
if(udp4_csum_init(skb,udp_hdr(skb),IPPROTO_UDP)) {
    return NF_DROP;
}
else {
    //start modifying skb
}
```

1. Does `udp4_csum_init` covers the UDP header and payload?
2. Am I right that the IP packet header is already validated, since the netfilter hook is called in `ip_rcv`?
3. What is the difference between `udp4_csum_init`, `udp_lib_checksum_comblete(skb)` and `udp_v4_check(len,saddr,daddr,base)`?
4. How can I avoid an additional checksum validation in the UDP stack itself after the datagrams leave the netfilter hook and are receipt by the local UDP stack. Is this possible by setting `skb->csum_valid = 1`?

BR